# How to dynamically adapt the layout of child elements to parent container's width?

Tags: html, responsive-design

What I want to achieve is an adaptive inner content layout relative to the parent container's width. Not too sure if using CSS media queries is an option here since they refer to screen width rather than to a specific container width. I want the same code to display a set of thumbnails either in 2, 3 or 4 columns depending on what container it is wrapped within.

I'm looking for an "automated" way of doing it rather than have to manually play with css. In other words, a "responsive layout" that would use "max-parent-container-width" instead of max-"device-width" if that makes sense.

Is there a solution to this, please?

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, an easy way would be to put a class name on the parent container. But to do that you need to know how the parent is shown either on serverside, or by JS.
I have not heard of a "like-media-query" solution for divs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept known as Element Queries (http://www.xanthir.com/b4PR0) that addresses this issue.

While I have not used this, there is an experimental implementation on GitHub https://github.com/wemakeweb/element-queries

This is suppose to let you write queries like:

```
 @media only screen and (element: .widget) and (element-max-height: 30px)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, robtarr, this solution seems to be working partially, it only calculates the element width once on page load, if I resize the browser I also need to refresh the page for the trick to take effect...

Comment: @user2501106 I just added a new solution that does not suffer from this sort of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is (IMO) a better solution that provides 1:1 parity with the API surface of Media Queries, but scoped to individual elements: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2014/04/18/element-queries-from-the-feet-up/ (script and demo included). While the syntax/approach it uses is a bit different It is completely dynamic, so there's no need to invoke methods when you change styles or query rules, and it covers anything you can do in a Media Query.

Once you include the tiny, 100 LOC script, you can style elements using the following:

**HTML**

```
<section media="query(small, (max-width: 300px) and (max-height: 300px))">

  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>

</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section[matched-media~="small"] {
  font-size: 50%; /* small text for a wee lil element! */
}

/* Multiple matches example: */

section[matched-media~="small skinny"] {
  ...
}
```

Put your `query()` declarations in the `media=""` attribute of any element, then when a query is matched, it will be added by the script to the `matched-media=""` attribute of the element. You can add queries to new elements (simply by using `setAttribute('media', ...)`) at any time during the page lifecycle, and it never requires you to invoke any JS, all attribute parsing and query matching is async and automatic! Checkout the much more detailed explanation about the mechanics of the solution in the article mentioned above - it includes a demo, and repos with two versions of the script.